# Nicescroll plugin for jquery Syntax error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery.nicescroll.min.js in website that I'm building. I use Dreamweaver CS4 to edit it, and give me a Syntax error on line 44, that is the following code:

```
!/INPUT|SELECT|TEXTAREA/i.test(c.nodeName))return!a.ispage&&e.hasmousecapture&&c.setCapture(),a.opt.touchbehavior?(c.onclick&&!c._onclick&&(c._onclick=c.onclick,c.onclick=function(b){if(a.hasmoving)return!1;c._onclick.call(this,b)}),a.cancelEvent(b)):a.stopPropagation(b);/SUBMIT|CANCEL|BUTTON/i.test(f(c).attr("type"))&&(pc={tg:c,click:!1},a.preventclick=pc)}}};a.ontouchend=function(b){if(!a.rail.drag)return!0;if(2==a.rail.drag.pt){if(b.pointerType&&2!=b.pointerType&&"touch"!=b.pointerType)return!1;
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Detect a sytanx error

Comment: Have you tried using uncompressed version? https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll/blob/master/jquery.nicescroll.js

Comment: Yes, have the same error

Comment: @Overnet, can you paste the error message?

Comment: There is a syntax error on line 42 of jquey.nicescroll.min.js. Code hinting may not work until you fix this error.